# base64 -d decodes, but says invalid input

Tags: linux, bash, echo, base64

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
me@box:~$ echo "eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJiYXoiOiJiYXQifQ" | base64 -di
{"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}base64: invalid input
```

Comment: I have this happen on Windows 10 when I install the GNU base64 binary there, I simply ignore it and copy my decoded output and utilize it.

Comment: Mine says invalid input too!  aW52YWxpZCBpbnB1dAo=

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you do the reverse, you'll note that the string isn't complete:

```bsh
$ echo '{"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}' | base64
eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJiYXoiOiJiYXQifQo=

$ echo "eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJiYXoiOiJiYXQifQo=" | base64 -di
{"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}
```

---

Extracts of [Why does base64 encoding require padding if the input length is not divisible by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-require-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-by)

> **What are Padding Characters?**
>
> Padding characters help satisfy length requirements and carry no meaning.
>
> However, padding is useful in situations where base64 encoded strings
> are concatenated in such a way that the lengths of the individual
> sequences are lost, as might happen, for example, in a very simple
> network protocol.
>
> If unpadded strings are concatenated, it's impossible to recover the
> original data because information about the number of odd bytes at the
> end of each individual sequence is lost. However, if padded sequences
> are used, there's no ambiguity, and the sequence as a whole can be
> decoded correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I really wish that error message had been a little more helpful.

Comment: Note that the string you used here is slightly different than the original, as `echo` adds a trailing newline. The original string without it would be correctly padded as `...ifQ==`. In this case, both versions do require padding though.

Comment: ```echo -n '{"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}' | base64
eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJiYXoiOiJiYXQifQ==```

Comment: Keep in mind the "input length" referred to is in bytes. If referring to the number of characters, the length should be divisible by 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You save me

Answer (score 14):

The command-line tool is picky about the presence of padding characters. That string is 34 characters long, so there should be two `=` signs as padding at the end.

```
$ echo "eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJiYXoiOiJiYXQifQ==" | base64 -di; echo
{"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}
```

Answer (score 8):

GNU's `base64 -d` requires proper padding (input length must be a multiple of 4). Other `base64` decoders may be smarter and not require padding (e.g. Mac/BSD `base64 -D` does not require padding).

Here's a bash command that can automatically pad the `base64` string properly. Then you won't get the "invalid input" error.

```bsh
str="eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJiYXoiOiJiYXQifQ"

echo "$str"==== | fold -w 4 | sed '$ d' | tr -d '\n' | base64 --decode
```

Explanation:

- `echo "$str"====` appends 4 equal signs
- `fold -w 4` split every 4 characters into separate lines
- `sed '$ d'` deletes the last line (the extraneous padding)
- `tr -d '\n'` joins all lines

Comment: Or `str=$str===; echo ${str:0:${#str}&-4}`. PS you wrote `bash64` where you meant `base64`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the catch! Fixed the typo.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a way to fix the padding in bash.